# Typescript generated JS files getting debugger on sourceMappingURL= line

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, typescript

I'm trying to get typescript debugging working, but when i generate the map files (Web Essentials) and then run the project, VS.net 2012 catches in the debugger on the //@ sourceMappingURL= XXXX.xxxx.js.map line at the bottom of the generated .js files.

How do I stop it and make it debug properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the latest IE roll-up that fixes bugs but also changes conditional compilation rules. As a result //@ is seen as a conditional statement in IE 9 and 10 (not 11 and I don't know about 8, but likely not) and is executed like any other conditional compilation statement. The result is it errors.

This is because the syntax for script maps was changed to //# recently and Typescript has yet to update to it. They promise this will be done for 0.9.1.0 (not 0.9.0.1) which should be soon and then the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you have internet explorer 10 installed and run through that.

Comment: I'm using IE 10 (and 11) and it starts debugging fine. The problem is that VS.net hits what it thinks is an error on the //@ sourceMappingURL= XXXX.xxxx.js.map line at the bottom of the .js file when the file is loading on the page. It then debugs fine, but when you have a couple of dozen debug scripts not bundled for testing it makes it brutal to click through them all.